# Neo4j data modeling: private owned nodes, rich relationships, locks

Tags: performance, neo4j, scalability, data-modeling, spring-data-neo4j-4

Versions used: Neo4j 3.0.6 with Spring-data-neo4j 4.2.0.M1 for POJO mapping

I'm trying to choose how to model data with neo4j and compare benefits/drawbacks of different solutions.

Requirements:

- A Movie has a dynamic list of metadata (a metadata has 3 properties: 'key', 'value', 'locale'). The number of metadata for a movie is not known in advance, neither are the possible keys. They have to be separable from the other Movie technical properties because they are localized and considered as business data.
- Metadata are owned by the Movie and always accessed from the Movie. They cannot be shared with other movies
- Fast fetch queries must be possible on metadata values

Movie metadata example:

```
Movie metadata
  locale 'en_GB':
    title: 'Jurassic Park'
    description: 'description in english'
  locale 'fr_FR':
    description: 'description en francais'
  locale 'none':
    actor: 'Jeff Goldblum'
```

[image]
Solution A

- **One node per metadata** (with 3 properties per node: 'key', 'value', 'locale')
- Drawback: **private owned concept** to be implemented (delete of Metadata orphan nodes to be managed manually because not supported by spring-data-neo4j/neo4j-ogm)

Solution B

- **One unique node per locale** (with 1 property: 'locale') (example: 'en_GB')
- Metadata as **rich relationships** (with 2 relationship properties: 'key', 'value')
- Drawback: to create the relationship, **a lock must be taken** on Locale node

Does someone has experience about solution B ? **How bad is it to need to lock a node that will be shared by million of other nodes ?**
What is the **impact on performances and scalability ?**

Does someone has a **better modeling solution ?**

Comment: It would help to know a bit more about the metadata. Does each user have its own metadata about a movie, or is it not user specific? Is there any reason you can't store the metadata as properties on the movie nodes? Are some pieces of metadata meant to act like tags (meaning you might query from metadata to movies)? Or are you ever only going to be accessing metadata from a movie, rather than directly?

Comment: No, metadata are not user specific. But they are localized (I didn't mention this to simplify). I think the only way to store metadata on movie nodes is inside arrays right ? But this would not be efficient for fetch queries. We have to be able to filter movies based on their metadata. And yes, we are always accessing metadata from a movie.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by only being able to store metadata within arrays. Is there some reason you can't just set properties on your movie nodes? You can always filter on node properties within your WHERE clauses. I'm still curious what kind of metadata this is supposed to be...what differentiates it from the node properties you were planning on using? Can you provide some examples of this metadata?

Comment: A movie has a list of metadata. For example: metadata1: {key='Title', value='Men in black'}, metadata2: {key='Director', value='Spielberg'}. The number of metadata is not known in advance, neither are the possible keys. So this is a dynamic list of properties. Sorry, it wasn't clear. And maybe I'm missing something but I don't see any easy way of modeling this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl,dr: go with approach A. Don't bother with orphaned `:Locale` nodes except for periodic cleanup, they will have no effect on query performance.

Your approach 'A' is by far the better solution. You do need to move that data off of the `:Movie` node, you are correct, because it will have to be either a nested Map or a list of Maps, neither of which is supported by Node properties. For storage, you could convert these to a Map of lists, but that will be very difficult to query, much less query quickly. Your concern about "orphaned" nodes is insubstantial; it will affect query performance and data size trivially if at all, and is incredibly easy to clean up periodically to ease your mind in any case.

```
MATCH (x:Locale) WHERE NOT (x) <- [:METADATA] - () DETACH DELETE x
```

Do that once a month, or never even, it really won't affect you much. Your query is already constrained by the rest of the path, so unless orphaned `:Locale` nodes are going to outnumber attached ones substantially, you're only adding a small percentage to what is already likely the largest set in your query, which will also be dropped by query operation on the first pass.

As for locking, it will only affect write queries anyway, and only while a write transaction is open. You can run a million read-only queries while the write is going on and nothing will be affected. Despite that, the second model is susceptible to slow query performance, because as mentioned above, you can't put indexes on relationship properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can just store the "metadata" *directly* as properties of each `Movie` node (without resorting to `key` and `value`). This is the simplest approach, which avoids locking concerns and minimizes the number nodes and relationships required. You can freely add more properties to a node at any time. This approach would also allow you to add indexes for specific `Movie` properties that you need to access quickly when kicking off your queries.

For example:

```
CREATE (m:Movie {id: 123, title: 'Men in black', director: 'Barry Sonnenfeld'});
```

[UPDATE]

If you need to keep your "metadata" cleanly separated from your "data" and you also need to be able to localize the metadata (including the specification of a `locale` property), then you can associate each `Movie` node with a single `Metadata` node for each locale. A `Metadata` node would *directly* contain all the metadata properties for a single locale for a specific `Movie` node.

Cypher can be used to perform "cascading deletes". For example:

```
MATCH (m:Movie {id: 123})
OPTIONAL MATCH p=(m)-->()
DELETE p;
```

Comment: It is a simple approach you're right. But I need to distinguish metadata from other attributes because they are business information separated from the other technical attributes.
And I also forgot an important part (too much simplification I’m sorry), metadata also has a 'locale' property (used to group metadata per language). I'm sorry I should have said it before, it changes everything. I will update the first post with these details.

Comment: Yes exactly, so it will look pretty much like solution A (except that we will not have one node per metadata). This solution works, however the drawback is for example to manage cascade deletes manually (what is not supported by spring-data-neo4j that I use). I was hoping to find a solution where I can avoid that.

Comment: You can use Cypher to perform cascading deletes.

Comment: Yes it is what we were doing. The problem is more to manage metadata removal. We had to manually delete nodes that were not used anymore, but we would like to find a simpler approach if possible. What is great with solution B is that we can add/remove metadata and also remove the movie, we don't have to manage manually any other node than the movie itself since everything is on relationships.

Comment: But locking may force you to serialize deletion requests. Also, you cannot create indexes on relationship properties.